# C# Interface containing an array of interface, hierarchy

Tags: c#, interface

I have an Interface for a master-detail common interface hierarchy:

```
public interface ITModel
{
    ITPeriodHead[] PeriodHeads { get; set; }
}
```

I try to use it this way:

```
public class T19Model:ITModel
{
    public T19Item[] Items { get; set; }

    **public T19PeriodHead[] PeriodHeads { get; set; }**

}
```

The array of **PeriodHeads** causes error at compile time,
despite **T19PeriodHead** implements ITPeriodHead, like this:

```
 public class T19PeriodHead : BaseTPeriodHead, ITPeriodHead
{ ...
```

What is the solution? If I use the array of ITPeriodHead, I will not be able to access the periodhead items members, properties, methods....

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: What is the error, exactly?

Comment: Does the user of the property need to overwrite items in the array (e.g. by doing `model.PeriodHeads[2] = new PeriodHead;`?

Comment: This is a tricky problem with no great solution. Fyi I'm going to do a series of blog posts about it later this month, so read that if this topic interests you.

Answer (score 4):

You have to honor the interface contract.  You are returning a more specific class that the interface defines, so you are not fully defining the interface.

You *could* explicitly implement the interface, but you have an issue with the setter - what if someone tries to `set` the property to an array of objects that are not `T19PeriodHead`s?:

```
public class T19Model:ITModel
{
    public T19Item[] Items { get; set; }

    public T19PeriodHead[] PeriodHeads { get; set; }

    ITPeriodHead[] ITModel.PeriodHeads 
    { 
        get {return PeriodHeads;}
        set {/* what to do here if value is not an array of T19PeriodHeads? */}
    }
}
```

If you do not need a setter for the array property (maybe an `Add` method instead?) then you are fine.

Comment: Thank you, now I make a try.

Comment: Beware though; if you assign an instance of this class to a variable of type `ITModel` (perhaps by passing it to a method which accepts such a parameter type) you will be able to do something like `model.PeriodHeads[0] = new IncompatiblePeriodHead()` which will cause a `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException` exception. So just be aware that this is not a typesafe solution.

Comment: I removed the "set", it seems to be useless.

Comment: @Estevez If you removed the set, it won't compile unless you remove it in the interface itself.

Comment: Yes, I removed it in the interface.

Comment: @Estevez Does the property has to of type array? If you just need a readonly access to the elements, you can use `IEnumerable<ITPeriodHead>`, that will prevent you from getting `ArrayTypeMismatchException` as Matthew said.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's why I didn't add any code to `set` (and suggested it be removed). There's no way to limit the input value to a `T19PeriodHead[]`.  You could _try_ to cast, but what if it fails?  Too many variables to make a suggestion. If the setter is removed then there's no issue - and I like the suggestion of changing it to an `IEnumerable<ITPeriodHead>`

Comment: Also if you need the collection's count, but otherwise only need to access it via `IEnumerable<ITPeriodHead>`, you can use `IReadOnlyCollection<ITPeriodHead>` (requires .Net 4.5x)